# Is DDD fit for our scenario?

Tags: database, dns, domain-driven-design

We are trying to come up with an API and serve data-intensive services to potential users.

Our scenario: we are more of less a data vendor where we store massive amount of data in normalized database and use queries to retrieve them to be displayed in data-driven web applications. Now, we want to create an API that clients can use to create their own frontend.

Given the scenario, does DDD help here?

From all the readings, DDD helps when you have complex event logic, but here all we are doing is putting things together from the database and serving them.

Or, would you say that we could build API based NOT on our database structure, but on its own domain model?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the application needs are only querying never think of DDD.. and Please refer [cqrs](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/)

in which Udi clearly explain why we should not use the domain model for querying